# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) - why am i getting this?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1241

I am trying to run a query but I am getting the above error. can anyone let me know why am I getting it.

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute`
SET `used_for_sort_by` = 1
WHERE attribute_id = (
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `entity_type_id` = (SELECT `entity_type_id` FROM `eav_entity_type` WHERE `entity_model` = "catalog/product") AND `attribute_code` = "created_at");
```

Comment: The select list from the first sub query in your WHERE clause must return only ONE COLUMN as you are trying to match it aganst one column i.e. `attribute_id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `attribute_id = (select * . . .`.  Presumably, `eav_attribute` has more than one column.

You need to specify the particular column, something like this:

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute`
    SET `used_for_sort_by` = 1
    WHERE attribute_id = (SELECT ea.attribute_id  -- this is a guess
                          FROM `eav_attribute` ea
                          WHERE `entity_type_id` = (SELECT `entity_type_id` 
                                                    FROM `eav_entity_type` 
                                                    WHERE `entity_model` = 'catalog/product'
                                                   ) AND
                               `attribute_code` = 'created_at'
                         );
```

Comment: That was absolutely right! Thank you Gordon.